# Rich text box in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, richtextbox

I have created rich text box in crystal reports for displaying product description. Everything is displaying properly but it is not taking more than 65534 characters. I need to display more than 65534, so please any one can help me to use is there any other control like richtext box to display the data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of Crystal Reports. 
Your options

1. in your query split the field in to multiple 65534 character length fields for each row (problem would be how many fields to produce 1,2,3,4,5...could be an unknown quantity)
2. in your query split the row into multiple rows and group by product having a 65534 char length field for each new row.  Example would be

   ProductID,  ProductName,   ProductDescription

   1,          P1,            [65534 characters]

   1,          P1,            [more text]

   2,          P2,            [65534 characters]

   2,          P2,            [65534 characters]

   2,          P2,           [More text]
3. Finally export the description to a file and insert the file via a hyperlink in the report or an OLE object.

Comment: Thanks John, but I am exporting report to pdf format. How can I export to pdf format if i give hyperlink.

Comment: I believe the pdf exports supports the creation of hyperlinks.  But note that was not the only option I provided.  you could try option 1 or 2