# Not showing table borders in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a richtextbox in my vb.net 2008 application. I was able to save the content including and i can view it through rich text box. But when i added that rich text box to crystal report, all contents will show, but table borders and lines are not showing.

IS there any limitations on crystal report or i am doing it wrongly

Comment: i have saved my rtf file in access database, through crystal report viewer i am trying to display.

Answer (score 0):

In format object box, Paragraph tab, change Text interpretation to "RTF text"

Comment: if you save that contents in rtf file, opening in "wordpad" (not in WORD) , are you able to see all borders?

Comment: and also check length of your contents

Comment: Also, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719265/rich-text-box-in-crystal-reports

Comment: try export in pdf, and check in pdf file also

Comment: then, i think it is OK, sometimes crystal report viewer does not display borders properly. Try to zoom and check

Comment: no, its not properly aligned as well, only table part. remaining is perfect.